# Hotkey for doing sudo suggestions

Tags: sudo, keyboard-shortcuts

On Ubuntu and Debian, often if I try to run a program I will get a message that says something to the effect of:

> You don't have that program. To get it type sudo -apt -get -install
>   programName

(or some variation on that). Then I usually type exactly the command that was just suggested.

Is there a hotkey that will automatically type the suggested command for me, e.g., I type something like <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> and `sudo -apt -get -install programName` is automatically typed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow this link to bind commands.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command

Bind to any key you want: `sudo apt-get -install !:0`

`!:0` is the last command run, `!:1` the first param, etc. `!!` is the last command line. This is all buried in the bash docs.

Hope that answers everything.

Caveat: I tested this code with `echo !:0` not `sudo apt-get -install !:0` for obvious reasons. I ran `ls` first and then pressed the <kbd>F1</kbd> key (where I bound it).  I got it to say `echo !:0`, then expand to `echo ls`, and then write the letters `ls` to the terminal. I see no reason why this won't work for you though.